# MS Excel 2007: How to keep same scaling of font size for multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, scaling

I have multiple sheets on Excel 2007. Unfortunately, the number of columns and their widths are different. I set all sheets to scale to 1 page. However, different sheets scale differently, and the output looks ugly. Is there a way force scaling all sheets by same factor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale Excel spreadsheet printout from the ribbon on the top > Page Layout > Scale to Fit:
[image: Scale to fit]

You could either fix the number of pages wide/high (and scale/percentage as a variable) or to fix the scale/percentage (and number of pages as a variable).  You cannot fix both of them, for instance, you can not print a table with 100 columns and 1000 rows on 1 page (A4 size or letter size), while maintaining the scale at 100%.

If you wish to make the print-out of all spreadsheets look the same scale, you have to make the scale (i.e. the percentage) the same across all worksheets, and leaving "Width" and "Height" as Automatic.

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved years of issue! :D